# How to make sure that an image doesn't disappear when tapped too many times? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, variables, integer

I am working on an app and I have an image that changes when you click on it. However, there is a bug in the app and if you accidentally click one too many time on it the image completely disappears. I want to set a maximum value to the variable integerValue so that it prevents it from being tapped further. Could someone please help me and give an answer in Swift 4?
Here is the code.

```
var integerValue = 1
```

The maximum value should be 9.

First time I update the variable:

```
@objc private func updateProgress() {
    integerValue += 1
    if integerValue < 10 {
     self.updateImage()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(integerValue-1, forKey: String(day))
    self.displayLabelScreen()
    }
```

Second time I update the variable:

```
@objc private func deleteProgress() {
        integerValue -= 1
        if integerValue > 0 {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(integerValue-1, forKey: String(day))
        self.updateImage()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Show the code you have that updates `integerValue`. If you don't want it to be more than 9 then don't set it to a higher value than that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: So what do you want different from the code you posted?

Comment: In the app that I made, when I click too many times on the image, it runs out of image to use and the image disappears altogether. I want to set a maximum value to the integer value so that it will not be able to be tapped further. I will add an extra bit of code to the question which may help me get an answer.

Comment: Move your increment/decrement inside the `if` statement so you only change it if it is currently valid.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try it.

Comment: It didn't work. The outcome was still the same.

Comment: It won't be if you do it correctly. You have to change the condition too.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean? Could you send me some code, please? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code you posted and the need to keep `integerValue` within the range 1-9, update your code as follows:

```
@objc private func updateProgress() {
    // Only increment if the new value will be 9 or less
    if integerValue < 9 {
        integerValue += 1
        self.updateImage()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(integerValue, forKey: String(day))
        self.displayLabelScreen()
    }
}

@objc private func deleteProgress() {
    // Only decrement if the new value will be 1 or more
    if integerValue > 1 {
        integerValue -= 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(integerValue, forKey: String(day))
        self.updateImage()
    }
}
```